# Data visualization for performance trend of students

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

`df.head(6)` :

```
Student_ID   Subject      Weekly_Feedback       Feedack_questions             Exam_Phase
100101       Physics       Poor                 How was physics class?        Mid term
100101       Physics       Excellent            How was physics class?        Mid term
100101       Physics       Good                 How was the Presentation?     Final
100102       Chemistry     Good                 How was chemistry class?      Final
100102         NaN         Good                 How was over all experience?  Mid term
100103       Mathematics   Good                 NaN                           Midterm
100103       Mathematics   Excellent            NaN                           Final
```

How can I visualize this data in different ways when the dataframe has all categorical values, either using `matplotlib` or `seaborn` library?

Also, I want to visualize the Student performance trend (i.e,  `Student_ID` = 100101, how this student's performance fluctuated (from Poor to excellent to good) using line graph using `Weekly_Feedback` column entries).

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? what didn't work?

Comment: I could only infer graphs based on value_counts, i.e, df['Exam_Phase'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar'). I'm not exactly getting ideas over how I could draw the performance trend of students.

Comment: I would map the feeback column to integer values